# what do '\r?\n\r?\n[\-\w+\.]+[>#]$' AND '\r\n][\-\w+\.]+(?:\([^\)]+\))?[>#] ?$' do?

Tags: python, regex

I've put some hours in learning what this Regex do in Exscript module, but I just could not figure it out.

This module ios.py if for handling the prompt in Cisco equipment .

```
_password_re     = [re.compile(r'[\r\n]Password:$')]

_first_prompt_re = re.compile(r'\r?\n\r?\n[\-\w+\.]+[>#]$')

_prompt_re       = [re.compile(r'[\r\n][\-\w+\.]+(?:\([^\)]+\))?[>#] ?$')]
```

Could anyone help me on this one ?

thank you very much

Comment: Can you give an example of what it you are trying to match?  Do you have examples of successful matches?

Comment: This question does not show any research effort.  If you spent "some hours" studying this, you should have at least a partial understanding.  Which parts have you figured out, and which parts are you still unsure about?  On the parts you are unsure about, what do you *think* they might be doing?

Answer (score 5):

Try to use [Debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/) to visulize the regex:

```
\r?\n\r?\n[\-\w+\.]+[>#]$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/xbKp76ctRNdkabV8)

```
[\r\n][\-\w+\.]+(?:\([^\)]+\))?[>#] ?$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/esOSBzqqL_wUVfQV)

Comment: Thankyou for sharing Debuggex - extremely useful - I'm bookmarking that now!